# Create User Group using agsxmpp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, agsxmpp

I'm using agsxmpp SDK for interacting with openfire server. I'm trying  to create a User Group using agsxmpp sdk but cannot really find any documentation about how to do that.

Can any provide any link or code sample about how to got about creating a user group and adding a user to it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no group concept in `agsxmpp`.Instead you can join a room with specific service like 
`roomname@conference.(server address)`.you can simply add a service using `Openfire`.Here is a code
 that can help you

```
/////code to be part of a room

var input = new frmInputBox("Enter your Nickname for the chatroom", "Nickname", "Nickname");


        if (input.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

        {
            // string nickname = "shan";

            // string j = "";

            string Nickname = input.Result;

            input = new frmInputBox("Enter the Jid of the room to join (e.g jdev@conference.jabber.org)", "Room");

          if (input.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)


            {

                Jid jid = new Jid((string)node.Tag);
                string nickname = input.Result;
                frmGroupChat gc = new frmGroupChat(this.XmppCon, jid, nickname);
                gc.Show(); }}
```

Comment: XmppCon is the connection object and gc is object for groupchat window.if you have doubt further you can look up at Miniclient byAlex